# Changes to config variables aren't persisten laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5, config

I'm having a problem where I need to change a config variable used by oauth2 server based on client-id. This is the configuration:

```
'grant_types' => [
        'password' => [
            'class' => '\League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant',
            'callback' => '\App\Api\OAuth2\PasswordGrantVerifier@verify',
            'access_token_ttl' => 3600
        ],
]
```

Then before i issue a token with `Authorizer::issueAccessToken();` I set the config variable: `config(['oauth2.grant_types.password.access_token_ttl' => 86400]);` if I then run `dd(config('oauth2'));` I get:

```
'grant_types' => array:1 [
        'password' => array:3 [
            'class' => '\League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant',
            'callback' => '\App\Api\OAuth2\PasswordGrantVerifier@verify',
            'access_token_ttl' => 86400
        ],
]
```

But if I let the code run and issue the token the response is still:

```
{
    "access_token": "HOoODcDzXilakd5TtOv4qqBSBUwEqqWhIL36ALdM",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "6mfyizKlRGC55x6ZY8ROx24UcVeWfljikNZv6ME7",
    "allowed_scopes": [
      "*"
    ],
    "user_is_activated": true
}
```

If i hardcode the value `'access_token_ttl' => 86400` I get the desired result of:

```
{
    "access_token": "HOoODcDzXilakd5TtOv4qqBSBUwEqqWhIL36ALdM",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "refresh_token": "6mfyizKlRGC55x6ZY8ROx24UcVeWfljikNZv6ME7",
    "allowed_scopes": [
      "*"
    ],
    "user_is_activated": true
}
```

The problem is that `access_token_ttl` needs to be dynamic based on the client id. I can't make changes to the vendor library because this would break in future updates. Does someone know of a way to change config variables application wide at runtime that still persists in different methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the class already being provided at the login route. Fixed it by checking the `Request` class for the `client_id` in the AuthServiceProvider and changing the config there.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you haven't cached your config, run `php artisan config:clear` to reset the config cache. You can run `php artisan config:cache` on your production server after a deployment for a performance boost.

Comment: If that was the problem I would've noticed it, because then it wouldn't have changed the value of the response when I hardcode the default value of ```access_token_ttl``` but it did so it's not a cache issue.